# Dell monitors keep blank after initial start

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card

We have Dell T1650 PCs with 2 nVidia graphic adapters / Windows 7 and 4 attached monitors.

At initial start all screens are blank, the computer does not show anything.  If powered off by pressing the hardware power button and then restarting all monitors show a picture. The Windows event log shows only the errors, that the machine was shut down unexpectedly.

The last entry with blank screen seems to be that user specific dlls for every application are loaded.

How can I find out the real problem?

---

Problem with both answers 
The PSU question: Both cards are low voltage cards with together 40 Watt. The cards where choosen so that they fit for the PSU. Dell offered a more costly card which needed 60 Watt (and does not provide the needed 2560*1600 resolution), so it should be fine.

There is also no upgrade from Dell atm for the PC. Driver and bios are at latest revision.

And I still want to know if there is a way to have more feedback from the system if something is missing.

I also believe that the system does not fail to boot, but it is just showing nothing (all latest drivers)

---

Update:

The systems boot normally, if it is not to cold in the room.

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

If it is warm, everything seems to work well.

If it is cold (e.g. somebody opened a window to get fresh air, with -10° it gets soon quite cold) the other systems does not start up initially, the only display something with a second start.

For me it would be understandable: 
To hot -> system temperature to hot -> refuse to work to secure system.

But 
To cold -> ??? -> graphic adapter does not show anything

Can anybody explain the "???"-part?

Comment: Have you checked that your PSU meets the power requirements for 2 cards?

Comment: Both cards are low voltage cards with together 40 Watt. The cards where choosen so that they fit for the PSU. Dell offered a more costly card which needed 60 Watt (and does not provide the needed 2560*1600 resolution), so it should be fine. The other thing is that not all PCs with 2 cards show the problem, only some of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. How are you seeing the Windows Event log?
2. Does the motherboard have a dedicated 'on-board' adaptor?
3. Have you changed the 'preferred' adaptor in the BIOS to the add-in card(s)?
4. Have you tried disabling the on-board display adaptor?

If you are unable to disable the on-board then you will need to, upon booting (with a monitor plugged into the on-board so you see the POST screen, then the desktop displayed on the monitor)  select each of the displays on the additional cards (within the Windows Display panel) and choose to 'Extend my desktop to this display' for each.

[image]

Comment: 1. Initial start in the morning is not showing anything on monitors. After cold restart (press power button) system boots up. Eventlog is shown via eventvwr. 2. Motherboard has a on board adapter, b ut no way to disable it manually. however if something is attached at motherboard adapter, an error message is shown at boot that configuration is not allowed, something like " if additional card is available onboard adapter can not be used". 3. Therefore - no, it is not possible to disable it. 4. Is not possible. The model does not allow to have onboard and additional card mixed.

Comment: 1. Just because you are not seeing anything, doesn't mean the system is failing to boot. 3 + 4. You may have to take the issue up with Dell, possibly look around for BIOS revisions/updates which will give you the features you need. If there are none (and you cannot get support) then what you are doing is not possible with the motherboard. You've tried all the 'usual' things.

Comment: There is no upgrade from Dell atm for the PC. Driver and bios are at latest revision. As 2 low voltage cards where added instead of buying a more costly card from dell which would not fit our needs (2560 resolution (just Dual DVI-D needed), there is no much support from Dell.

And I still want to know if there is a way to have more feedback from the system if something is missing.

I also believe that the system does not fail to boot, but it is just showing nothing (all latest drivers)